# Any change on page prompts a message before navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to prompt a message to the user **Do You want to save the changes??**  if he made some changes in any control on the current page before navigation to other page. what is the best way to do this. every control has their events. Like text-box key change event. combo box `selectedItemChange` event. But a lot of code have to be written in this scenario. I want this modification on each page of the project.... 
Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

you'll atleast need to define the `event handlers` for the controls that can be changed.

Inside the `event handlers` you can just set a `boolean` variable to true, and check the value of the variable in `OnNavigatedFrom` method of the Page, and accordingly show the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Silverlight Navigation framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx

There are events that get raised (navigating, navigated, etc...) where you can prompt the user and cancel the navigation.